# How do I construct binary trees using boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, binary-tree, shared-ptr

I am trying to use boost shared pointers to construct a binary tree and store the nodes in a STL map.  I have taken a common binary tree example and tried to turn the pointers into shared_ptr as follows.  I may have made it more complicated than needed because I thought using templates would be a good idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#include "boost/smart_ptr.hpp"

//typedef boost::shared_ptr<node<int> >  nodePtr;

template <typename T>
class node
{
public:

    T nodeData;
    boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > *left, *right;

    // default constructor. data not initialized
    node() {}

     // initialize the data members
    node (const T& item, 
          boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > lptr = NULL, 
          boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > rptr = NULL) :
          nodeValue(item), left(lptr), right(rptr) {}
};

template <typename T>
void inorderOutput(boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > t)
{
   // the traversal terminates on a empty subtree
   if (t != NULL)
   {
      inorderOutput(t->left);       // descend left
      cout << t->nodeData << ", ";  // output the node
      inorderOutput(t->right);      // descend right
   }
}

int main()
{
    // a few nodes to assemble into a tree
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > d( new node<char>('D') );
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > e( new node<char>('E') );
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > f( new node<char>('F') );
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > g( new node<char>('G') );

    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > b( new node<char>('B',d, e) );
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > c( new node<char>('C',f, g) );
    boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > a( new node<char>('A',b, c) );

    // now store the node pointers for later reference
    map<string, boost::shared_ptr<node<char> > > nodeMap;
    nodeMap["D"] = d;
    nodeMap["A"] = a;
    // etc.

    // inorder traversal of nodes  
    cout << "Inorder:      " ;
    inorderOutput(a);
    cout << endl;

    // Test to see if a node has children
    if (( nodeMap["A"]->left != NULL ) || (nodeMap["A"]->right != NULL ) ) 
    {
        cout << "Node A has children!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am building in Visual Studio Express 2010 and get the following error:

```
1>  SharedPtr.vcxproj -> c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SharedPtr\Debug\SharedPtr1.exe
2>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sharedptr\sharedptr2\sharedptr2.cpp(27): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              T=node<char>
2>          ]
2>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
2>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sharedptr\sharedptr2\sharedptr2.cpp(49): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Apparently the node constructor is not properly defined.  I have been spinning my wheels for a while now trying to figure out what I am doing wrong (probably several things!).  Also, assuming I can get this to compile, is the test for node children going to work?  Previous experiments have given me some reason to believe it is not this easy.  Finally, I have commented out the typdef at the top of the listing because I was not using that properly either.  Can anyone suggest a way to clean up this code?

John

Comment: Why are you keeping a pointer to a `shared_ptr`? Are you clear on how they work?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 node (const T& item, 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > lptr = NULL, 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > rptr = NULL) :
      nodeValue(item), left(lptr), right(rptr) {}
 };
```

to

```
 node (const T& item, 
      const boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >& lptr = boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >(), 
      const boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >& rptr = boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >()) :
      nodeValue(item), left(lptr), right(rptr) {}
 };
```

and as pointed out, make 'left' and 'right' a non-pointer boost_shared_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` would me `#define`d to 0 in most implementations, and it looks like guessing `boost::shared_ptr` has no idea what to do with it.

Change

```
boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > *left, *right;
```

to

```
boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > left, right;
```

and

```
node (const T& item, 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > lptr = NULL, 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > rptr = NULL) :
```

to

```
node (const T& item, 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > lptr = boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >(), 
      boost::shared_ptr<node<T> > rptr = boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >()) :
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I am not sure I understand what you did with the constructor defaults.  What exactly does lptr = boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >() do?

Comment: @JohnSchroeder That constructs a `boost::shared_ptr` with the default constructor, which I guess gives an empty pointer. `boost::shared_ptr<node<T> >()` is a call to its constructor essentially.